# HTML How to pass two variables on a radio button press?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, onclick, parameter-passing

How can I pass two variables on a button press? This may seem basic but I am completely stuck!

I am creating a table that has a radio button on the left side, and when you press it I want to retrieve two values. I am currently retrieving one value but I am missing the other.

Currently I am passing one value onto my onRadioButtonPress function like this:

```
 html += "<tr><td><center><br>
          <input type='radio' 
             onclick='onRadioButtonPress(this.value)' 
             name='siteChosen' 
             value='"+siteIDArray[i]+"'>
           <center></td>";
```

And I am calling the function like this:

```
//function for on radio button press
   function onRadioButtonPress(val){

      //blah blah blah
 }
```

Which is working great, but how do I add a second value of

> usagePlanArray[i]

to my on onClick function? How would I change my input?

Thank you in advance!!! :) Please let me know if you have any questions, or if I missed something that would help you out!

---

SOLVED!

Please see the marked answer from @mplungjan. I used his alternative method that is useful for jQuerys.

Comment: wt is the second value??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
value='"+siteIDArray[i]+"|"+usagePlanArray[i]+"'>
```

but you need to remove the newlines from the HTML too

Then in the function you can use

```
var vals=val.split("|");
var siteID=vals[0], usagePlan=vars[1];
```

Alternative - especially useful in jQUery:

```
html += "<tr><td><center><br><input type='radio'"+
        " onclick='onRadioButtonPress(this)' name='siteChosen'"+
        " data-siteid='"+siteIDArray[i]+"'"+
        " data-usageplan='"+usagePlanArray[i]+"'><center></td>";
```

and

```
function onRadioButtonPress(rad) {
  var siteID=rad.getAttribute("data-siteid"),
      usageplan=rad.getAttribute("data-usageplan"),
}
```

Comment: Can I ask something silly? Why do you pass 'rad' to the function? Is it because it is a radio button?

Comment: Yes. Note the (this) in the call

Comment: It worked! You rock! Please add an equals sign in the html after the data-usageplan!

Comment: Yeah I was on my mobile and the string was very long :}

Answer (score 0):

Pass an array in JSON:

```
   value='"+JSON.stringify(siteIDArray)+"'>
```

That would pass the entire Array as JSON Array string.

Passing to single values:

```
    value='["+siteIDArray[i] + "," + usagePlanArray[i] + "]'>
```

or, as an object:

```
    value='{ \"val1\":\""+siteIDArray[i] + "\",\"val2\":\"" + usagePlanArray[i] + "\"]'>
```

Now decode in the function

```
   values = JSON.parse(val);
   ...
   xyz = values[0];  // for the array
   ...
   xyz = values.val1; // for the object
```

code could even be optimized, if you direct pass that to the onclick instead of the value parameter, but that might have some additional purposes.

Comment: I am still a little confused. So could I use JSON like this: value='"+JSON.stringify(siteIDArray[i], usagePlanArray[i])+"'>

Comment: Let me try it and see how it goes.

Comment: In this case would values[0] be the siteIDArray[i] and values[1] be the usagePlanArray[i]?

Comment: This is far too complicated way to do this

Comment: @MadsterMaddness Yepp.

Comment: @mplungjan it's not the easiest way, actually for certain things I even go with your solution, but there are caveats as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the same index for both arrays, why not just store the index as the value and look up the desired values in the click callback?

```
var html= "";

var siteIDArray = [1, 5, 2, 33];
var usagePlanArray = ["unlimited", "20gb", "10gb", "5gb" ]

function arrayCombo(index){
    return {siteId: siteIDArray[index], usagePlan: usagePlanArray[index]};   
}

for(var i=0; i<siteIDArray.length; i++){
    html += "<tr><td><center><br><input type='radio' name='siteChosen' value="+i+"><center></td>";
}

$('#content').html(html);

$('input').on('click', function(event){
    //Do whatever you want with the values you are looking for here
    var x = arrayCombo(this.value);
    alert(x.siteId+", "+x.usagePlan);
});
```

Also, to demonstrate this tight-knit relationship between your arrays it would probably be better to store their values at shared indexes as properties of objects in an array.

Comment: The static arrays are just place holders for the example. Their values could be replaced with results of an ajax call or however you are supplying the data.